# Laravel 5.8 + deeplinks in email

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, email-validation

I have the following problems. On Laravel project, everythings working fine. However, we want to modify email verify and password reset email buttons.
Currently they are pointing to https://application.domain.com/...

We want to modify them to a deeplink, so a mobile app will open: for example myapp://verify/...

When I inherit and modify notification blade file, email is arriving, but the buttons are miss the href attribute...
Cant find solution to make them work

Comment: Clients such as Gmail remove deep-links, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23575553/ios-deep-linking-is-stripped-out-in-gmail. You will want deep-links that use http(s), and/or Universal Links.

Comment: I see. Thank you mate.